# How to resume execution after pressing pause/break key in windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard, terminal

Whilst compiling a rather huge python extension in cmd with the command **pip install**. I wanted to pause and look at some of the output, so I pressed the  <kbd>Pause / Break</kbd>  key on my keyboard.

Pressing the key again did nothing and looking in task manager revealed that **cl.exe** (The current running process in the terminal) was at 0% instead of 100% CPU load. So it appears the compiler process was quite definitely paused midway.

How do I resume the execution, because I don't want to rerun the entire compilation again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> will resume a paused terminal.

I cant find any documentation about this for windows, but I tried it and it seems to work.